# Remote access denied when I accessed mysqldb in amazon-ec2. (1045, "Access denied for user 'user-name'@'some-ip')

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I make an ec2-user server in AWS. And then install mysql
I already googled this problem then I checked I did well.

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.58, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

First, set aws inbound 0.0.0.0:3306

`# netstat -tln`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Second, create mysql user 'yj' for 0.0.0.0. (I tried '%' also. But it's not working. So I tried '0.0.0.0', also.)

`mysql> select host, user, password from mysql.user;`

```
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host             | user | password                                  |
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost        | root | *some-password                            |
| ip-172-31-86-160 | root |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1        | root |                                           |
| ::1              | root |                                           |
| localhost        |      |                                           |
| ip-172-31-86-160 |      |                                           |
| 0.0.0.0          | yj   | *some-password                            |
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Third, check the `/etc/my.cnf` file.

`# cat /etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

People says modify `bind-address=127.0.0.1` to `bind-address=0.0.0.0`. But my .cnf file doesn't have any bind-address. So I was trying to find another conf file in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` or `/etc/mysql.conf` and so on. But there is nothing without `/etc/my.cnf` file.

Could you tell me that is there anything what I miss?

Comment: `And then install mysql` ... may we ask why you aren't just using RDS to manage your database needs?  This is what I would suggest to you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The reason why there is web server. :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You mean I have to `install mysql`?

Comment: Why can't the web server talk to RDS?  I would find it hard to believe that you can't make RDS work with your setup.  This is stuff AWS has had years to perfect.

Comment: I mean there is web page made of PHP, Apache. And MySQL connects with them. And I didn't make this aws server. So I don't know why my friend doesn't use RDS... Was she annoyed to make one more server? maybe.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not the native speaker of English so I do not know I understand well. Anyway, your opinion is it's better using RDS than ec2?

Comment: Please see here: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

I solved the problem it was because of schools wi-fi. Maybe there is something...you know.

So connection rejected with the message that `'Connection failed: Access denied for user 'yj'@'some-ip'`. And `'some-ip'` is different what I was using. So I create user using that ip. Now, working well.

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
CREATE USER 'yj'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'yj'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can check the user priviledges by:

```
SHOW GRANTS yj;
```

Try to replace `'localhost'` with the host you actually use, I guess it's:

```
'0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. It's solved in an unexpected direction. :)